# How to open a new tab in File Explorer provided that it opens the current tab and it shows on the title bar?

Tags: windows, windows-11

Please see the screenshot:

[image: Please check the image]

Is there any shortcut for it?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> opens the current tab but on a new window. I want it on the same window!

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + T opens a new tab

CTRL + N opens a new window with your current tab

You want a shortcut that can duplicate your current tab. unfortunately this is not available yet.